IUC Notation in Frieze Patterns
I was given the following frieze patterns with their corresponding IUC notations:

Hop (T): p1111
Step (TG): p1a1
Jump (THG): p1m1
Sidle (TV): pm11
Spinning hop (TR): p112
Spinning jump (TVHRG): pmm2
Spinning sidle (TVRG): pma2

I believe the transformations involved in each pattern are in the parenthesized parts (for example, "THG" means translation (T), horizontal reflection (H) and horizontal glide reflection (G), where G arises from the combination of T and H).
The part that I just could not understand is how the IUC notation works in frieze patterns. We were told that "p" means "primitive cell" and "c" means "face-centered cell", but I don't know what that means exactly. I've looked at various source materials and I seem to get mixed definitions that really confused me even more.
What do the letters and numbers mean in the notation? Why is the IUC for each frieze pattern defined that way?

You may find interesting this article
